# Values aren't updated when using operator[][] on type: map<int, map<int, int> >

Tags: c++, dictionary, insert, iterator

I have a program that is acting as kind of a *virtual router* ... I store my forwarding tables in maps of maps: `map<int, map<int,int> >` ---
Prior to the call I'm trying to do, the following is the current state of my forwarding table, initialized earlier:

```
//destination | hop, cost
map<int, map<int,int> > forwardingTable;
forwardingTable[3701][3701] = 8;
```

Now I'm trying to do the following:

```
//iterators and pathCost are initialized earlier
forwardingTable[topoIt->first][*pIter] = pathCost;
cout << "forwardingTable[" << topoIt->first << "][" << *pIter << "] = " << pathCost << endl;
```

With this, I get output of:

```
forwardingTable[3701][3705] = 6
```

However, in the same method, when I loop over my forwarding table:

```
forwardingTableIter iter = forwardingTable.begin(); 
while(iter != forwardingTable.end())
{
    map<int,int, less<int> >::iterator inner_it = iter->second.begin();
    cout << "--Dest: " << iter->first << "\tHop: " << inner_it->first << "\tCost: " << inner_it->second << endl;
    iter++;
}
```

I get this output when it gets to node 3701:

```
//still hop 3701, cost of 8
--Dest: 3701    Hop: 3701   Cost: 8
```

Am I misunderstanding the [][] operator here? I was under the impression that it would search for the referenced element, and if found, update it - otherwise, insert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the `3705`.

```
forwardingTable[3701][3705] = 6
```